# Weird shrinkwrap behavior with SVG

Tags: svg, shrinkwrap

**Context:** I'm trying to place an SVG file to a non-flat surface using shrinkwrap.

**Problem:** For some reason, the svg file gets deformed in a strange way, leaving black lines behind as if it wasn't flat... I've tried every shrinkwrap option and doesn't matter how much offset I put it remains the same.

[image]

The SVG file is exported from Illustrator and the vertices are perfect there is nothing out of place, this happens only when applying the shrtinkwrap. Anybody got any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you shrink wrap to a non-flat surface you need to have more internal topology so that the mesh could be shaped to fit the target.

Convert it to a mesh and Remesh that with Quad and Preserve Mesh Boundary. Then shrink wrap it to the target.

The topology can also be made better after Beautify Faces.

Comment: This is what happens when I apply Quad:
[link](https://imgur.com/lRKzAwe)

Comment: Well, that doesn't look ok... how does it look before quad?

Comment: Looks OK, but as you can see where there are too many stacked edges is where the problem occurs when shrinkwrapping, is there a way of getting rid of those? Not even sure if that's suppose to happen... [image](https://imgur.com/a/UflBNgp)

Comment: Try run Beautify Faces to get rid of those thin, elongated triangles. Will probably make the result look better even without remeshing with quad.

Comment: Beautify Faces did at least 99% of the job, didn't need to apply Quad. Thanks!